# Customising Export options in Crystal Report Viewer

Tags: crystal-reports

I am using SAP crystal reports in Visual Studio 2010.I want to customise crystal report viewer 
export options. That is, I want to show only export to pdf,and to excel in my crystal report viewer.
How I can do this

Comment: possible duplicate of [Crystal Report Viewer - Programmatically restricting File Format options](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380956/crystal-report-viewer-programmatically-restricting-file-format-options)

Answer (score 6):

Your can restrict the ReportViewer in 13.0.x using:

```
ReportViewer.AllowedExportFormats = (int)(ViewerExportFormats.ExcelFormat | ViewerExportFormats.PdfFormat);
```

Answer (score 4):

First of all include below namespace on top of your code behind:

**using CrystalDecisions.Shared;**

then,write below code in your page load event as:

**protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)**
        **{**

```
       CrystalReportViewer2.AllowedExportFormats = (int) (ViewerExportFormats.ExcelRecordFormat | ViewerExportFormats.PdfFormat);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

this.crystalReportViewer1.AllowedExportFormats = (int)CrystalDecisions.Shared.ViewerExportFormats.PdfFormat;