# Display PDF and Excel export options in Crystal Reports?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, crystal-reports-2008

I need to Remove the Word, Rpt and rtf option in Crystal report Export option. Is it possible? 
I need only two option pdf and Excel. If possible please advice.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Answer (score 2):

Using CRVS2010 , you can remove unwanted export Option.

A new feature of CRVS2010 is the ability to modify the available export formats from the viewer export button. The following C# sample code demonstrates how to set the CrystalReportViewer to export only to PDF and Excel file formats:

```
int exportFormatFlags = (int)(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ViewerExportFormats.PdfFormat | CrystalDecisions.Shared.ViewerExportFormats.ExcelFormat);
CrystalReportViewer1.AllowedExportFormats = exportFormatFlags;
```

For More Details Please refer below link..

http://scn.sap.com/community/crystal-reports-for-visual-studio/blog/2011/01/26/export-file-formats-for-sap-crystal-reports-for-vs-2010

Comment: Getting errpr in ViewerExportFormats. I am using version Visual studio 2008, Crystal Reoprt Version=10.5.3700.0